# Why is [0] needed for getElementsByClassName to work when there's only one class to select?

Tags: javascript

I tried using `let modal = document.getElementsByClassName('modal')` to select an element with the class `modal`. It only worked after using node selection to select the first result: `let modal = document.getElementsByClassName('modal')[0]`. I know the method `Document.getElementsByClassName()` returns child elements which have all of the given class names, but there's only one element in my HTML with that class. I confirmed this in my browser's dev tools by using `var x = document.getElementsByClassName('modal').length` and logging the value of x to the console (it returned 1 as expected).
Could someone explain why node selection is needed in this case?

Edit: My question is different than the one marked as a duplicate. In that question, they are asking the difference between methods than return a single element and those that return an array-like collection of elements. I'm already aware `getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like collection of elements, whereas the other methods return one element. My question is why do you need to specify the index in a case where all elements of a class are returned but there's only one element with a class (so one item, the correct item, is returned).

Comment: Use `querySelector` instead when only selecting one element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)

Comment: The reason is because it's an array-like object. Same as an array with a single value in it; you can't just call to it and get the single value, you must specify an index.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) will return a list of elements with the given class name. Even if there is only one element with that class name it will be in a Node List which is why you have to use the `[0]`

Comment: Why is it in some cases [0] is not needed?

Comment: How do you mean some cases?  getElementsByClassName will always return a node list.

Comment: Looking at your code pen and logging `matchingCard` out to the console, it is still an `[object HTMLCollection]`

Answer (score 3):

It is needed because [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) Returns an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) and not a single element.

To get the item without using `[0]`, use a [query selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) instead, this will give you the item instead of a collection of items.

```
let modal = document.querySelector('.modal')
console.log(modal)
```

Comment: Note--querySelector elements are not live. My JS manipulates the dom (adding a class that causes the modal to be shown), so in my case I can't use querySelector and have it work correctly.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. A query selector can be ran after the class has been dynamically added....

Comment: In my code, when the user wins the game, modal.classList.add('show'); is added, causing the modal to appear (set to visible in CSS). If I use let modal = document.querySelector('.modal'), the class is not added to the element with class modal.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByClassName
```

will return array of element who has this class

Comment: I think the OP is clearly not understanding how arrays of length 1 work. They continue to say "I know it returns an array", but "why do I have to use index 0 if there's only element". It might help to address that specifically.

Comment: I know arrays start at 0. My point of confusion is it makes sense to select a specific index if there are multiple items in the array-like object. But if you know there's just one, why specify?